# Can't record steps in BadBoy Softwere for JMeter

Tags: jmeter, badboy

I am using Bad Boy for recording steps and exporting it to JMeter

I am getting two major issues

[image]

The first one is some JS error in some libraries

And the second one is when i am importing JMeter Script the path that i used in badboy isn't the same in JMeter

In BadBoy : https://SomePath
In Jmeter : https://SomePath/Login/login

Comment: Badboy is an outdated tool and shall not be used for Jmeter script creation. There are many options available for creating JMeter scripts. This link could be useful http://pragmatictestlabs.com/2021/10/20/jmeter-building-test-scripts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do you really want to use a tool from 2009 in 2021 (almost 2022?)? There are several other recording options like:

   - JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)
   - [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-install-and-upgrade-the-blazemeter-chrome-extension)

   I don't really understand French hence cannot comment anything on the error you're getting however I can assume that Badboy comes with a really old version of Internet Explorer bundled and this old IE cannot properly handle/render the website you're trying to record.
2. You should not be comparing JMeter to Badboy, you should compare JMeter to real browser, the requests from JMeter should match the ones you see in network tab of your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) so cross check them using either JMeter's [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener or better an external sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Comment: the two solution that you provided can't work in a company computer the chrome extension are not allowed and you can't change proxy settings this is why i used BadBoy

Comment: 1. In [Firefox browser](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) there is separate proxy configuration. 2. You can also export requests from your browser developer tools in form of .HAR and either use [Har2jmeter](https://martkos-it.co.uk/blog/har-to-jmx-file) standalone tool or online [BlazeMeter Converter](https://converter.blazemeter.com/).

Comment: Thank you for yout replay i will try it